# Load GZIP Binary Data in a column in Snowflake DB

Tags: blob, gzip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql, snowflake-task

I have a csv file which has two columns. First Column is an id and second column is the compressed GZIP binary data. I want to load this record into the Snowflake table with having two columns id as number data type and bin_text as binary data type.

Tried to load csv file(tab as seperator) with "COPY into" command but the GZIP compressed binary data has a multiple new lines which snowflake considers as seperate recod.

I need to load the whole GZIP compressed binary data which has multiple new lines into a single record.

Please help.

Table structure - id as number, compress_data as Binary

For example, 
first record - 1, gzip of ("hello world. This is snowflake example. I am having some doubts so went for stackoverflow to clear the doubts. The issue is to load the bianry data into snowflake table. I have a csv file which has two columns. First Column is an id and second column is the compressed GZIP binary data. I want to load this record into the Snowflake table with having two columns id as number data type and bin_text as binary data type. Tried to load csv file(tab as seperator) with "COPY into" command but the GZIP compressed binary data has a multiple new lines which snowflake considers as seperate recod. I need to load the whole GZIP compressed binary data which has multiple new lines into a single record.").

To generate the compressed format of the text, i am using the following command:

```
echo "hello world. This is snowflake example. I am having some doubts so went for stackoverflow to clear the doubts. The issue is to load the bianry data into snowflake table. I have a csv file which has two columns. First Column is an id and second column is the compressed GZIP binary data. I want to load this record into the Snowflake table with having two columns id as number data type and bin_text as binary data type. Tried to load csv file(tab as seperator) with "COPY into" command but the GZIP compressed binary data has a multiple new lines which snowflake considers as seperate recod. I need to load the whole GZIP compressed binary data which has multiple new lines into a single record." | gzip -cf9 | wc -l
```

this command produces 4 lines as compressed output. I want to store this 4 lines as a single record.

The output file is a CSV(tab seperated) stored in Internal stage of Snowflake.

Copy command options used:

```
copy into compress
from (
select
t.$1,
t.$2
from <INTERNAL STAGE> t
)
file_format = ( type = csv
field_delimiter='\t' escape_unenclosed_field=none
binary_format=UTF8);
```

Comment: Would you be able to share some example data and what COPY INTO options you are using (commands)?  What is the table DDL? Are you specifying the delimiters and file format options as desired to load your data?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Comment: @SuzyLockwood edited the question to provide the details.

Comment: Perhaps try setting: BINARY_FORMAT = UTF8 in the file format (or directly in the copy into command) and see if that has any effect: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-csv  I think I would also experiment with COMPRESS=none and take a look at the record delimiter options.

Comment: If the *field* is compressed rather than the file, you need to use the Snowflake decompress function on that field. Snowflake supports field-level compression/decompression methods of Snappy, Zlib, Zstd, and BZ2. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/compress.html. While Gzip uses similar libraries as Zlib, it has extensions so it's not binary compatible. If you can use a different compression on the front end, then you can use Snowflake's decompress function.

Comment: @MikeDonovan Have tried with BINARY_FORMAT = UTF8 option, couldnt able to load the binary data.

Comment: @Kameshwar can you modify input data and base64 encode the GZIP compressed string?  That should solve the newline issue.

Comment: @NatTaylor I tried to convert to Base64 encode but still the size of the data is almost 25MB and couldnt able to load.

Comment: when trying to reproduce this note: Don't use Try_to_binary - it will store it as null. I also ran into the 256 size limit limit - I also found this: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009a8OViSAM/any-way-to-increase-the-size-limit-for-set-variables  ask support :)